# How to handle success response in PayU biz in surl?

Tags: php, android, payu

In Android side I am getting merchant data : null. 
How can I show success result in App side?
After successful payment PayU server returns some response in `$_POST`.

```
$result = '';
foreach($_POST as $key=> $value){

    $result .= $key . '=' . $value . ',';
    $input = rtrim($result , ','); 
}
echo "<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function AndroidSuccess()
            { 
                PayU.onSuccess('status=success'); 
            } 
            AndroidSuccess($input);

        </script>
     </head>
      <body>
        </body>
</html>";
```

in android side I am capturing response like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == PayuConstants.PAYU_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (data != null) {
        Log.e("data", ""+data.getExtras().toString());

        new AlertDialog.Builder(WalletFragment.this)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setMessage("Payu's Data : " + data.getStringExtra("payu_response") + "\n\n\n Merchant's Data: " + data.getStringExtra("result"))
            .setPositiveButton(
                android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(
                        DialogInterface dialog, 
                        int whichButton
                    ) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            ).show();

            Log.e("Payu's Data :"," "+" "+ data.getStringExtra("payu_response") + "\n\n\n Merchant's Data: " + data.getStringExtra("result") );
            Log.e("TAG","Merchant data:"+data.getStringExtra("result"));

        } else {
    Toast.makeText(WalletFragment.this, getString(R.string.could_not_receive_data), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a webserver which handles the PayU processing, if not, let me know.

Once you receive the PayU response, ideally, you would store it in database (preferably encrypted and against an order ID and a user ID).

Then on the Android side, you would communicate with the MySQL server either directly (not recommended) or through a PHP script which would read the database result and pass the values to your app (recommended).

Comment: As I said, you would either need to connect to database directly, but it's a high security risk, so write a server side script which would fetch the data from database and echo it out in JSON format and then hit the server side script's link from the app after a specific time.